# Lost feature - how do I get an overview of the strings contained in a xib in XCode 4?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, internationalization, xib

the [Internationalization Guide mentions a sweet feature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html) - by choosing "Tools > Strings" you should be able to view and edit all the strings contained in a xib file in a nice table. It's available for Interface Builder 3.0 and newer, the guide says.

Since XCode4 however there is no Interface Builder and no "Tools > Strings" menu anymore. I've looked pretty much everywhere, but I can't seem to find that feature.

Can you guys tell me where they've hidden this jewel? Or did they maybe drop it?

thanks,
Toastor

**Edit:**

The whole guide I mentioned seems to be a bit outdated. Any suggestions for more up-to-date guides or tutorials (covering internationalization using XCode4) would be very welcome!

**Edit 2:**

Never mind about the guide. I found a short and sweet guide at [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial). Still curious about the string summary, though.

Comment: That feature does not exist in the current version of Xcode 4.0. Using ibtool is the best alternative.

Comment: Do you have some sort of source for this information or is this your own conclusion from being unable to find it? If you're sure about it you may want to post it as an answer (since this is what it is) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature does not exist in the current version of Xcode 4.0. Using ibtool is the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

you could use ibtool:

```
man ibtool
```

Comment: Yep I've seen this before. While this would work however, it would be a bit more tedious to edit the strings this way. And it lacks the neat interface ;)

Comment: uhh... terminal is the neat interface, sir ;)